# Is this a quotient ring?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I was reading Proposition 3.9 on p. 121 of the book *Algebraic Number Theory* by Jürgen Neukirch. It said:

*If $v$ is a discrete exponential valuation of $K$, then
$$
\mathcal{o}=\{x\in K|v(x)\ge0\}
$$
is a PID, hence a DVR. Suppose $v$ is normalized. Then the nonzero ideals of $\mathcal{o}$ are
$$
\mathfrak{p}^n=\pi^n\mathcal{o}=\{x\in K|v(x)\ge n\},\quad n\ge0,
$$
where $\pi$ is a prime element, i.e., $v(\pi)=1$. One has
$$
\mathfrak{p}^n/\mathfrak{p}^{n+1}\cong\mathcal{o}/\mathfrak{p}.
$$*

Please let me ask a few questions:

1. Is "prime element" here synonymous with prime elements of (the commutative ring) $\mathcal{o}$?
2. The isomorphism $\mathfrak{p}^n/\mathfrak{p}^{n+1}\cong\mathcal{o}/\mathfrak{p}$ being written, I guess this does not refer to isomorphism of rings, does it? Or just of the underlying additive groups?

Thank you very much for answering.

Comment: 1. yes. 2. an isomorphism of $\mathfrak o/\mathfrak p$-modules.

Comment: But $\mathcal{o}/\mathfrak{p}$ is a field, is not it?

Comment: Thank you for your answers.